# Skipping GET URL that returns ModelAndView from Spring Security Config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, staticresource, modelandview

I am working on Spring Boot security 3.2.1 and implemented JWT Authentication in my project. However, now I am not able to get my HTML pages which were working earlier. I have added these resource path in my Spring Security Config class but still it is returning me 403. Before implementing Spring Security, I was able to get my html files using URL - http://localhost:8080/expensemanager/html/application.html

Here is my Project Structure

[image]

Here is my Security Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> { request
            
            // Registration Controller
            .requestMatchers("/registration/validateuserid").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/registration/registeruser").permitAll()
            
            // Auth Controller
            .requestMatchers("/auth/createtoken").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/auth/refreshtoken").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())
            
            // Master Controller
            .requestMatchers("/master/**").permitAll()
            
            // Resource Controller
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/application").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/report").permitAll()
            
            // Report Controller
            .requestMatchers("/report/**").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name())
            
            // Expense Controller
            .requestMatchers("/expense/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())
            
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
        .sessionManagement(manager ->  {
            manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        })
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()).addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

And Here is my Controller Class serving html files,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ResourceController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage() {
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("html/login.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public ModelAndView getRegistrationPage() {
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("html/registration.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/application")
    public ModelAndView getApplicationPage() {
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("html/application.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/report")
    public ModelAndView getReportPage() {
        
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("html/report.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

And here is the response.

[image]
[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by following the guide here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html

Added below code in SpringSecurityConfig

```
//Permitting all my Dispatch Request
.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()

//Allowing all my resources, which is present in public folder  
.requestMatchers("/bootstrap/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/fontawesome/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/fuse/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/highcharts/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/html/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
.requestMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
```